# Why do (some )apps open in random workspaces when started from command line?

Tags: 11.04, unity, command-line, workspaces

In a gnome-terminal, I started Blender (any app would do, though I didn't many others) followed by an ampersand.   Nothing happened!   Some minutes later, discovered it had indeed opened, but was in a different workspace than where the gnome-terminal was.   Is this a bug or a "feature"?  Why did this happen, and is there a way to fix it?  (If it's really just a bug, I'll wait...)

This is on 11.04, with two monitors, everything straight "out of the box" no config tweaking yet.  (I can't find where to tweak things...)

Comment: Are you running unity?

Comment: Yup.  Didn't mention it as i wasn't sure it was relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might keep track of where the programs' windows are when you exit them or end the session; some programs remember what workspace their windows were last on and ask the window manager to move them back there.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: That will depend on the application, unfortunately.  KDE used to have options to control things like this for badly behaved applications, but they seem to have vanished in recent versions.